# Воспроизведение аудио с определённой позиции

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, html, аудио

Прошу помочь. Подскажите, пожалуйста, может, есть решения такой задачи, как воспроизведение аудиофайла на странице не с начала, а с определённой позиции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тэга `<audio>` есть такое свойство, как **currentTime**. Если установить для него новое значение, то, по идее, аудиофайл должен будет начать проигрывание с этого участка.

[Больше информации о параметрах](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement).

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо. Очень мне поможет данный Вами ответ.